# VBA Excel Username grants access followup question?

Tags: excel, vba

I was searching for a code to grant access by the username and found the question posted by user5836742 and the answer given by PeterT. Used the code it didn't work and I removed the test macro & it worked. I have copied the code I used below. The question I have is with this method it will show only the assigned sheet. But the user can right click and unhide other sheets. What can we do for that?

===CODE===

```
Public Sub ViewAuthorizedSheets(uname As String)
    Dim authSheets As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    uname = Environ("UserName")
    authSheets = GetAuthorizedSheets(uname)
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If sh.Name <> "AuthUsers" Then
            If InStr(1, authSheets, sh.Name, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Else
                sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            End If
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub

Function IsUserAuthorized(uname As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim userTbl As ListObject
    Dim userList As Range
    Dim allowedUser As Variant
    Dim allowed As Boolean

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AuthUsers")
    Set userTbl = ws.ListObjects("UserTable")
    Set userList = userTbl.ListColumns("Users").DataBodyRange
    allowed = False
    For Each allowedUser In userList
        If LCase(allowedUser) = LCase(uname) Then
            allowed = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next allowedUser
    Set userList = Nothing
    Set userTbl = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    IsUserAuthorized = allowed
End Function

Function GetAuthorizedSheets(uname As String) As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim userTbl As ListObject
    Dim userList As Range
    Dim allowedUser As Variant
    Dim allowed As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AuthUsers")
    Set userTbl = ws.ListObjects("UserTable")
    Set userList = userTbl.DataBodyRange
    allowed = False
    For Each allowedUser In userList.Columns(1).Cells
        If LCase(allowedUser) = LCase(uname) Then
            allowed = allowedUser.Offset(0, 1).value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next allowedUser
    Set userList = Nothing
    Set userTbl = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    GetAuthorizedSheets = allowed
End Function
```

Comment: Did you try **PROTECTING** the workbook?

Comment: I tried. Then the code doesn't work.

Comment: See PEH's answer. I guess you didn't use the correct protection settings.

Comment: Anyway hiding sheets is not secure. For both solutions I showed there is a workaround to make sheets visible again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want prevent that the user is able to unhide them you must use `xlSheetVeryHidden` instead of `xlSheetHidden`.

Alternatively you can protect your workbook using the [Workbook.Protect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.protect). But note then you need to unprotect it everytime before you change visibilty `sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible`.

In both cases note, that there will **always** be a workaround and hidden sheets can always be made visible by the user if he knows how to use VBA. Hiding sheets is no secure protection for your data.

Comment: You can but that password doesn't prevent the user to make a sheet visible again. You could run something like `Workbooks("YourWorkbook.xlsm").Sheets(1).Visible = xlSheetVisible` from any other workbooks VBA and it will make the first sheet in your workbook visible again.

Comment: This will be sufficient for the current requirement. Thanks! Peh.